# DBUnit throwing NoSuchColumnException while deleting the dataset

Tags: java, junit, dbunit

I am doing some unit testing using DBUnit. I am able to insert the dataset properly from the xml file but I am not able to clear the dataset after every thing is completed.

Below is my table schema for the ID column (I have ommitted other columns here):

```
FIELD        TYPE              COLLATION          NULL    KEY     DEFAULT       Extra           PRIVILEGES                     
-----------  ----------------  -----------------  ------  ------  ------------  --------------  -------------------------------
ID           INT(11) UNSIGNED  (NULL)             NO      PRI     (NULL)        AUTO_INCREMENT  SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,REFERENCES
```

Below is the XML sataset:

```
<dataset>
    <MY_TABLE NAME="NISAY" />
</dataset>
```

I am using `FlatXmlDataSetBuilder` for building the dataset. While creating, I am using `InsertIdentityOperation.INSERT.execute(iConnection, dataSet);` and for deleting I am using `InsertIdentityOperation.DELETE.execute(iConnection, dataSet);`

The dataset is inserted properly into the database but while deleting, it throws the below exception:

```
org.dbunit.dataset.NoSuchColumnException: MY_TABLE.ID -  (Non-uppercase input column: ID) in ColumnNameToIndexes cache map. Note that the map's column names are NOT case sensitive.
    at org.dbunit.dataset.AbstractTableMetaData.getColumnIndex(AbstractTableMetaData.java:117)
    at org.dbunit.dataset.AbstractTable.getColumnIndex(AbstractTable.java:78)
    at org.dbunit.dataset.DefaultTable.getValue(DefaultTable.java:197)
    at org.dbunit.operation.AbstractBatchOperation.execute(AbstractBatchOperation.java:189)
```

Just to test that every thing is proper, I had removed the `unsigned` constraint from ID column and used the below dataset:

```
<dataset>
    <MY_TABLE ID="-99" NAME="NISAY" />
</dataset>
```

Using the above, everything worked fine. However, the ID has to be `unsigned`. How do I tell DBUnit to ignore the Primary Key while deleting? I tried using Filters but not sure if they were configured properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, So the problem is that you cant give an ID in the XML file because the ID has to be auto generated. And DBUnit deletes the rows based on the primary key. Since I was not providing the primary key (i.e. ID) DBUnit failed to delete the dataset.

Solution:
Make a dummy primary key for the dataset.
First implement `IColumnFilter`

```
class MyPrimaryKeyFilter implements IColumnFilter {
        private String pseudoKey = null;

        MyPrimaryKeyFilter(String pseudoKey) {
            this.pseudoKey = pseudoKey;
        }

        public boolean accept(String tableName, Column column) {
            return column.getColumnName().equalsIgnoreCase(pseudoKey);
        }

}
```

Then set the `PROPERTY_PRIMARY_KEY_FILTER` as below:

```
DatabaseConfig config = iConnection.getConfig();
config.setProperty(DatabaseConfig.PROPERTY_PRIMARY_KEY_FILTER, new MyPrimaryKeyFilter("SOME_OTHER_COLUMN_TO_BE_TREATED_AS_PK"));
```

Now the column `SOME_OTHER_COLUMN_TO_BE_TREATED_AS_PK` will be treated as the primary key and you can provide any value for that column in the dataset XML file.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same error(NoSuchColumnException) on a specific column with a custom data type (used DatabaseConfig.PROPERTY_DATATYPE_FACTORY, new OracleDataTypeFactory()).

Was extracting the dataset with:

```
IDatabaseTester databaseTester =new JdbcDatabaseTester("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver",
            address, "user", "password", "schema");
QueryDataSet queryDataSet = new QueryDataSet(databaseTester.getConnection());

String query = "SELECT * FROM CARS WHERE ID LIKE '123456'";
queryDataSet.addTable("FACTORY.CARS", query);
```

And the above dataset was meant to be used in a:

```
DatabaseOperation.DELETE.execute(connection, queryDataSet);
```

Solved by changing the query to return only the colums necessary to identify the rows meant to be deleted (avoiding the rows with the custom data types) and the Exception ceased:

```
String query = "SELECT CAR_ID FROM CARS WHERE LICENSE_PLATE LIKE 'AB-FV-XY'";
```